# Returning data from POST using KnockoutJS + DurandalJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I've been working on this for too long.... And since jsfiddle doesn't support Durandal was hoping someone could shine some light on where the problem is. I am leaning towards my data bindings.

HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="row row-centered">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-4 col-sm2 col-centered">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          Contact
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" data-bind="value: email, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputText">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputText" data-bind="value: msg, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click:sendEmail, enable: name, enable: email, enable: msg">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ko if: debugTrue -->
<div class="row row-centered">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-4 col-sm2 col-centered">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Data Return
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body"> 
          <ul data-bind="foreach: debugInfo(), as: 'd'">
              <li data-bind="html: d"></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

Durandal:

```
define(function (require) {
  var app = require('durandal/app'),
      http = require('plugins/http'),
      ko = require('knockout');

  var url = '/api/api.php';

  return {
    name: ko.observable(),
    email: ko.observable(),
    msg: ko.observable(),
    debugInfo: ko.observableArray([]),

    sendEmail: function() {
      var qs = {
        method: 'email',
        name: this.name(),
        to: this.email(),
        msg: this.msg(),
      };
      var that = this;

      app.showMessage('Email sent to ' + this.name() + ' at ' + this.email());
      return http.post(url, qs).then(function(response) {
        that.debugInfo(response.items);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Returned from api.php:

```
{"images":1,"items":[1,2,3,4],"status":1}
```

So the problem is that when iterating through debugInfo() it is not populating.

ANy help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with what you have so far.

1. `var that = this;` is in the wrong spot.  this appears to represent the sendmail function and as such there is no debugInfo property associated with it.
2. You have a `<!-- ko if: debugTrue -->` knockout virtual element.  there is no corresponding debugTrue property on the viewmodel.
3. the binding that you need to use the foreach with an `as: d` is as follows

`<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: debugInfo, as: 'd'}">
  <li data-bind="html: d"></li>
</ul>`

Here is a  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1uy3wkn8/18/) then will hopefully help